# Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'description'

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Im a beginner to firebase and I am just following along the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joVi3thZOqc&t=301s and I'm getting this error " Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'description' " here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var conditionLable: UILabel!

    @IBAction func sunnyDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func FoggyDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let conditionRef = rootRef.child("condition")
        conditionRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in

            self.conditionLable.text = snapshot.value?.discription
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: In the title you say 'description', but code has `discription` (with an `i`). If that is a typo in your actual code, it could explain the problem.

Comment: There's another typo in conditionLabel ...

Comment: that was a typo. and you can ignore this question now I fixed it by changing this:     let conditionRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("condition")
         conditionRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in
            self.conditionLable.text = (snapshot.value as AnyObject).description

Comment: But if any one sees a problem with my code all help would still be appreciated Im still getting a signal SIGABRT in the app delegate.

Comment: @MikaelWeiss Chek `conditionLable` is properly connected in storyboard.

Comment: The label is connected correctly. and I just changed a little bit of my code in app delegate.swift and now Im getting a " Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 " I'm reading the answers for that on stackOverflow right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose is to get the **value** of **condition** key right?.

So use `snap.value` to get it.

```
let conditionRef = rootRef.child("condition")

conditionRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in
  let weather = snap.value as? String

  self.conditionLable.text = weather
})
```