# I am trying to query a firebase database in while the user is typing, but I keep getting this error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I found this code to query your database while the user is still typing, but the code was outdated and I've been updating it, but there's an error that I don't know how to fix.

```
func findFriends(text: String) -> Void {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        let user = User()
        let userArray = [User]()

            for u in snapshot.children{
                user.name = u.value!["name"] as? String
        }
    })
```

I get an error in the last line and it says:

> Value of type 'Any' has no member 'value'

Comment: Seems like the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42026284/4916627) although thats a different swift version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Any' has no subscript members (firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136026/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-firebase)

Comment: @AndréKool Looks similar, but I'm not to sure how i would implement this with my for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in `snapshot.children` are of type `Any`, which doesn't have a `value` property. To get at the `value` property you need to cast `u` to a `DataSnapshot`:

```
for userSnapshot in snapshot.children{
    let userSnapshot = userSnapshot as! DataSnapshot
    guard let dictionary = userSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
}
```

Alternatively, you put the cast in the loop:

```
for userSnapshot in in snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] ?? [] {
    guard let dictionary = userSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
    user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
}
```

Comment: I get this error when I try the first code. " Ambiguous reference to member 'value' "